# What is groupBy supposed to do?

Tags: haskell, haskell-platform

I wrote something using `Data.List.groupBy`. It didn't work as expected so I end up writting my own version of `groupBy` : after all I'm not sure that the `Data.List` one is supposed to do (there is no real documentation).

Anyway my tests passed with my version of `groupBy` whereas it fails with the `Data.List`. 
I found (thanks `quickcheck`) a case where the two function behaves differently, and I still don't understand why there is a difference between the two versions. Is the `Data.List` version buggy or is is mine ? (Of course mine is a naive implementation and is probably not the most efficient way to do so).

Here is the code :

```
import qualified Data.List as DL
import Data.Function (on)
import Test.QuickCheck

groupBy' :: (a -> a ->  Bool) -> [a] -> [[a]]
groupBy' _ [] = []
groupBy' eq (x:xs) = xLike:(groupBy' eq xNotLike) where
    xLike = x:[ e | e <- xs, x `eq` e  ]
    xNotLike = [ e | e <- xs, not $ x `eq` e  ]

head' [] = Nothing
head'  (x:xs) = Just x

prop_a s = (groupBy' by s) == (DL.groupBy by s) where
    types = s :: [String]
    by = (==) `on` head'
```

running in *ghc* `quickCheck prop_a` returns `["", "a", ""]`

```
*Main> groupBy' ((==) `on` head') ["","a",""]
[["",""],["a"]] # correct in my opinion
*Main> DL.groupBy ((==) `on` head') ["","a",""]
[[""],["a"],[""]] # incorrect.
```

What's happening ? I can't believe there is a bug in the haskell-platform .

Comment: The `groupBy` function breaks a list into pieces, such that `concat . groupBy f == id` (among other laws).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your version is *O* (*n*<sup>2</sup>) – which can be unacceptably slow in real-world use<sup>1</sup>.

The standard version avoids this by only grouping *adjacent* elements if they are equivalent. Hence,

> *Main> groupBy ((==) `on` head') ["", "", "a"]

will yield the result you're after.

A simple way to obtain "universal grouping" with `groupBy` is to first sort the list if that's feasible for the data type.

> *Main> groupBy ((==) `on` head') $ DL.sort ["", "a", ""]

The complexity of this is only *O* (*n* log *n*).

---

<sup>1</sup> This didn't prevent the committee from specifying `nub` as *O* (*n*<sup>2</sup>)...

Comment: Reading the `groupBy` doc I realize it group indeed adjacent and behave differently from what I need : a normal `group by`. I can do a sort indeed but didn't realize it was necessary. My version doesn't pretend to be usable in the realword and didn't add an unnecessary constraint on the argument. Apart from obvious performance reason, the "Ord" constraint is functionnaly unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

Data.List.groupBy in Haskell is a usability mistake! A user friendly groupBy should behave like this:

```
groupByWellBehaved p = foldr (\x rest -> if null rest
                                     then [[x]]
                                     else if p x (head (head rest))
                                          then (x : head rest) : (tail rest)
                                          else [x] : rest) []
```

Perhaps there is a better implementation, but at least this is O(n).